# Android Facebook SDK gives different user id's for the same application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

It's clear that Facebook SDK is started to generate different user id's for different applications after graph API v2.0 as stated in this document :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

The problem I have faced is that a user has different user id's for the same application logged in on different devices. It points to the same user if I open the user's facebook page using "www.facebook.com/userId" url.

How is this possible? Is there anyone else facing the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this problem across web and Android, and it turned out that the web application and Android application were actually linked to two completely different Facebook applications with different application IDs, even though the applications had the same name.

For example, the Web application was using the client ID and client secret of application https://developers.facebook.com/apps/0000000000001/ while the Android application was actually configured on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/0000000000002/

The Facebook User ID is intentionally different across those two different applications for improved security.